# Display CR values as scientific notation

Tags: crystal-reports, scientific-notation

I have a series of very small positive and negative values stored in oracle which I am attempting to display in crystal reports. Crystal is displaying all the values as 0. However if I turn the max decimal places on I will see some values as 0.00...00XY.

I would like these values simply displayed as scientific notation with something like 1.2E-12.

It seems crystal automatically converts very large values to SN, but not very small values?

Comment: I looked around myself and see what you're talking about.  Crystal doesn't appear to have a built-in method for handling small values. You might have to write your own function to handle it.

Comment: You are correct. For some reason CR does not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible so I went and created a view instead for each needed table. Kind of a dumb solution, but it seems the only way possible.